# react-native: modal components with zIndex in Flatlist does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, z-index, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I need to popup this Edit/Delete menu modal on top of the each data raw as menu UI

Used DragList as main component 'react-native-draglist'

```
  function renderItem(info) {

    const groupEditAndDelete = () => {
      return (
        <View transparent={true} style={[styles.authoritySelectModalStyle, { marginTop: 4 }]}>
          <FlatList
            data={dataEditAndUpdate}
            renderItem={changeAuthorityLevelItems}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            horizontal={false}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 16}}>
        <ExpandableDropdown
          onPressIn={handleDragStart}
          onPressOut={handleDragEnd}
          item={item}
          expanded={expanded}
          groupEditAndDelete={groupEditAndDelete}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 0, width: '100%'}}>
      <DragList
        data={dataTalentPoolGroup}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        onReordered={onReordered}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  authoritySelectModalStyle: {    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1200,
    shadowColor: Themes.COLORS.black,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.29,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,
    elevation: 7,
  },
})
```

[image]

I need to avoid the hiding this menu modal inside the data raw
[image]

As below UI

[image]

I think zIndex and the positions are correct.